# How to save a style in Excel

Tags: excel, format, stylesheet

I really don't use Excel often and I don't really know how it works when it starts to be complicated.

Let's say I have an Excel document, very beautiful with different colors and backgrounds for different cells, some font-size, alignments...

I export the data in a csv file ans re-import it in Excel.

Of course there is no style, everything is gone and displayed in a raw way.

Is it possible to save (I know I should not say that) the stylesheet?

I understand there are some themes in Excel but when I apply those themes it changes the size of the font... that's it... no colors no text align..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel styles only apply to manually selected ranges.

You could keep one file with the formatting as a template, open the new csv file, switch back to the template file, click on format painter (the yellow brush), switch back to the csv file, paste.

The format painter copies the formatting of a range to another range, so it will work as long as the selected ranges have of the same size.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to save it easily to a csv file.  You could go through the cells or ranges one by one in VBA and then save the format as a string to a file, but it would be a true labor of love, and you'd have to have the code in the receiving sheet to transform the strings back to the formats.

Or you can do what most do and save your file without data (and maybe formulas) as a template, and use that to create a new file based on that formatting whenever you need to.

Comment: I dont really want to save the style in the csv..myabe there is another way like those thmx files for themes

Comment: The only way is to save the sheet itself, then the formats come with it.  If you want to create a new sheet with that format, just copy the old one.  In fact, you could just clear all the data and formulas out of your existing one, and then save it as a template xlsx file, then recreate the file based on that.  I do that currently (though with formulas) for one particular spreadsheet.

Comment: ok... and if I have this template.xls, can I import a csv file inside at one point exactly ? (at the sixth lines for example)

Comment: You can always import a csv file, I'm not sure why you'd ask that.  Open your template file, save it as the new filename you want, then import the csv.